# host.docker.internal didn’t send any data for WebStatus endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to run https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers locally. I managed to setup all the 21 containers in my Docker Desktop and all the 21 containers are running.

[image]

But when I try to access to http://host.docker.internal:5107/ for WebStatus endpoint, I got this error. I have also run both powershell scripts at deploy/windows folder.

[image]

Comment: What response do you get if you try: http://localhost:5107 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*host.docker.internal* is for docker internal communication mainly - not external connection to container (for example from localhost). You can open any container in docker desktop and try clicking browse web (if applicable) or as suggested above in comments use localhost:5107

A little background from docker documentation:

*I want to connect from a container to a service on the host*

The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name *host.docker.internal* which **resolves to the internal IP address** used by the host. This is for development purpose and **does not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop.**

You can also reach the gateway using *gateway.docker.internal*